# How to integrate spring boot with angular2?

Tags: angular

i'm trying to integrate spring boot with angular2.
this is the service, it renders a list of cameras stored in a database

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/cameras")
public class CameraController {
 @Resource
    private CameraService cameraService;
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Camera> getAllCameras() {

        return this.cameraService.getAllCameras();
    }
```

I'm following this tuto to build angular2 app with spring boot backend:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhroyiYFmjc
this is a portion of  angular2 part:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app works!';
  cameras=[{id:"1",name:"camera1", place:"home"}];
  constructor(private http: Http){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get("http://localhost:9000/cameras").
    toPromise().then(r => r.json()).then(r =>this.cameras= r);

  }
}
```

Normally it should render the list of cameras stored in database but it shows me the default array:cameras=[{id:"1",name:"camera1", place:"home"}];I failed to call the backend service :( 
Thanks for your help :))

Comment: try :  `this.http.get("/cameras")`.

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: What error are you recieving? 404?

Comment: I bet you have a CORS error. Check you console. If so, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors